# How to make a graphic symbol draggable in FLASH?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Could you tell how the actionscript code would look like for such a job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use StartDrag() and StopDrag()

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Flash_drag_and_drop_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

do you mean Shape class object or Graphics class object? Shape class is derived from DisplayObject so there is no interactive support for this and one can not instantiate a Graphics class object. For making something drag-gable, one needs to put graphics in some Sprite object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

Create a MovieClip called "Circle". Right-click on the symbol in the library, choose Properties >  check the "Linkage" box, then "Export for Actionscript". Name the class "Circle". You can use flash.display.MovieClip as the base class.

Then, in the same folder as your .fla file, create a text file called "Circle.as" (remember to use a capital C, like you name the MovieClip) and type the following:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Circle extends MovieClip {
        public function Circle () {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

            this.buttonMode = true;
            this.mouseChildren = false;
        }

        private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            startDrag();
        }

        private function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            stopDrag();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there's an important aspect of it that hasn't been addressed...

Are you refering to a library symbol that is declared to be a "Graphic" (as opposed to a MovieClip or Button)?

If you are referring to the notion of a Library symbol that is a "Graphic" then you can't.  A Graphic can be thought of like a glorified "group" with the main difference being that a Graphic lives in the Library while a group does not.  Like a group, a Graphic allows you collect different items together in a single "container" and manipulate them in the .fla, but it doesn't actually exist as a programmatic construct in the published swf... so you can't add script or commands to a Graphic because as far as the flash player is concerned *There is no graphic.*

As an experiment, you can create a movieclip symbol in the library, then create another library item that is a graphic containing the movieclip.  Put both of these on frame 1 of an empty fla, with the following code:

```
for(var i:int = 0 ; ilen:int = this.numChildren ; i < ilen ; i++){
    trace(this.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Notice that both children are your MovieClip... the graphic is nowhere to be found.  This is why you can't add any script to a Graphic.

**So what can you do to solve this?**

If you absolutely need that symbol to be a Graphic in the library, and you absolutely need to be able to drag and drop it as a whole (or perform any other action on it) then you need to put it inside a MovieClip container and then drag/drop that MovieClip.